# Android: Recycler View with filterable interface crashes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-filterable

In my app I have implemented filterable interface in the recycler view adapter. The problem is when I enter the text and it is not in the list, the app crahses with following exception:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
   at in.droom.adapters.recyclerviewadapter.MultiSelectRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MultiSelectRecyclerViewAdapter.java:48)
   at in.droom.adapters.recyclerviewadapter.MultiSelectRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MultiSelectRecyclerViewAdapter.java:20)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5138)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4433)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4326)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1955)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1364)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1327)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:556)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2713)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3011)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1732)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1497)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:907)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:493)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.view
```

This is my adapter code:

```
public class MultiSelectRecyclerViewAdapter extends SelectableAdapter<MultiSelectRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

private ArrayList<FacetDataModel> mOriginalDataList;
private ArrayList<FacetDataModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
private Context mContext;
private int filterCategoryPosition;
private ViewHolder.ClickListener clickListener;

public MultiSelectRecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, int filterCategoryPosition, ArrayList<FacetDataModel> mOriginalDataList, ViewHolder.ClickListener clickListener) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.filterCategoryPosition = filterCategoryPosition;
    this.mOriginalDataList = mOriginalDataList;
    filteredList.addAll(mOriginalDataList);
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}

// Create new views
@Override
public MultiSelectRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                                    int viewType) {
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.row_facet_textview_checkbox, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView, clickListener);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    final FacetDataModel mFacetDataModel = filteredList.get(position);
    String facetName = DroomUtil.changeToCustomCamelCase(mFacetDataModel.getFacetDataName()) + " (" + String.valueOf(mFacetDataModel.getFacetDataValue() + ")");
    viewHolder.facet_name.setText(facetName);
    if (mFacetDataModel.isSelected()) {
        viewHolder.facet_tick_mark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        viewHolder.facet_tick_mark.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    viewHolder.itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.onItemClicked(filterCategoryPosition, position, mFacetDataModel);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (filteredList != null && !filteredList.isEmpty())
        return filteredList.size();
    else
        return mOriginalDataList.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            ArrayList<FacetDataModel> filteredResults = new ArrayList<>();
            //NEW CODE
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) {
                for (FacetDataModel item : mOriginalDataList) {
                    if (item.getFacetDataName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
                        filteredResults.add(item);
                    }
                }
                results.values = filteredResults;
                results.count = filteredResults.size();
            } else {
                synchronized (mOriginalDataList) {
                    results.values = mOriginalDataList;
                    results.count = mOriginalDataList.size();
                }
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            filteredList = (ArrayList<FacetDataModel>) filterResults.values;
            MultiSelectRecyclerViewAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}

protected ArrayList<FacetDataModel> getFilteredResults(String constraint) {
    ArrayList<FacetDataModel> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (FacetDataModel item : mOriginalDataList) {
        if (item.getFacetDataName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
            results.add(item);
        }
    }
    return results;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private RobotoLightTextView facet_name;
    private View itemLayoutView, divider;
    private ImageView facet_tick_mark;
    private ClickListener listener;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView, ClickListener listener) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        this.itemLayoutView = itemLayoutView;
        this.listener = listener;

        facet_name = (RobotoLightTextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.facet_name);
        divider = itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.divider);
        facet_tick_mark = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.facet_tick_mark);
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onItemClicked(int filterCategoryPosition, int filterDataPosition, FacetDataModel facetDataModel);
    }
}

public void refreshData(int filterCategoryPosition, ArrayList<FacetDataModel> mDataList) {
    this.filterCategoryPosition = filterCategoryPosition;
    this.mOriginalDataList = mDataList;
    this.filteredList.clear();
    this.filteredList.addAll(mDataList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

The line no. 48 in adapter is:

```
final FacetDataModel mFacetDataModel = filteredList.get(position);
```

I not getting what I am missing. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, the error is `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0`.

On `public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position)`, replace the first line of code with the following code and see if it works for you.

```
final FacetDataModel mFacetDataModel = (filteredList != null && !filteredList.isEmpty()) ? filteredList.get(position) : mOriginalDataList.get(position);
```